# How virtuoso do if-then rules inference?

Tags: if-statement, rdf, owl, virtuoso, inference

I am new to Openlink Virtuoso. And I want to do some inference rules based on if-then statements, like,

```
if (B is fatherof C & A is fatherof B) then (A is grandfatherof C).
```

According to [Virtuoso documentation of *Inference Rules & Reasoning*](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrule/), Virtuoso could use Ontology (Graph) to inference RDF.  Can Virtuoso use if-then statement inference rules?

Thank you !

Comment: in Virtuoso 8, it's possible.

Comment: do you want to apply forward or backward chaining? for the former, you could also execute a SPARQL Update query

Comment: Rules of various kinds are implemented in Virtuoso Enterprise Edition v8+. They are not available in Open Source Edition or any previous version. As AKSW suggests, you could run some query/ies that materialize new statements based on existing statements, but these would not be structured as if/then.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.And it actually works in Virtuoso 8! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtuoso 8.x supports Custom Reasoning & Inference Rules (using SPARQL as the Rules Language) in addition to Built-in Inference Rules from prior releases.

As a multi-model RDBMS that supports declarative interactions with relations represented as Tables or RDF Graphs, it has always been possible to implement custom inference rules by way of "magic predicates" (created using Virtuoso's SQL Stored Procedure Language) that dynamically materialize relations.

In the latest release of Virtuoso, we've simply exposed the existing "magic predicate" functionality using SPARQL as the Rules Language, courtesy of terms from the SPIN Vocabulary.

Live SPARQL Query Results links demonstrating Custom Reasoning and Inference Rules applied to a snippet of British Royal Family Relationship Types from DBpedia:

1. [Ancestors & Descendants](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=DEFINE%20input%3Amacro-lib%20%3Curn%3Aspin%3Ananotation%3Ademo%3Aroyal%3Afamily%3Alib%3E%20%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20rel%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fvocab%2Frelationship%2F%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0AWITH%20%3Curn%3Aspin%3Ananotation%3Ademo%3Aroyal%3Afamily%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fperson%20rel%3AancestorOf%20as%20%3Frelation%20%3Fdescendant%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20a%20%3C%23RoyalPerson%3E%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rel%3AancestorOf%20%3Fdescendant%0D%0A%09%20%20%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000)
2. [Siblings](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=DEFINE%20input%3Amacro-lib%20%3Curn%3Aspin%3Ananotation%3Ademo%3Aroyal%3Afamily%3Alib%3E%20%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20rel%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fvocab%2Frelationship%2F%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0AWITH%20%3Curn%3Aspin%3Ananotation%3Ademo%3Aroyal%3Afamily%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson%20rel%3AsiblingOf%20as%20%3Frelation%20%3FsiblingOf%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20%20a%20%3C%23RoyalPerson%3E%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rel%3AsiblingOf%20%20%3FsiblingOf%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000)
3. [Aunties](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=DEFINE%20input%3Amacro-lib%20%3Curn%3Aspin%3Ananotation%3Ademo%3Aroyal%3Afamily%3Alib%3E%20%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20rel%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fvocab%2Frelationship%2F%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0AWITH%20%3Curn%3Aspin%3Ananotation%3Ademo%3Aroyal%3Afamily%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fperson%20%3C%23hasAuntie%3E%20as%20%3Frelation%20%20%3FhasAuntie%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20a%20%3C%23RoyalPerson%3E%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%23hasAuntie%3E%20%3FhasAuntie%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000)
4. [Uncles](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=DEFINE%20input%3Amacro-lib%20%3Curn%3Aspin%3Ananotation%3Ademo%3Aroyal%3Afamily%3Alib%3E%20%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20rel%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fvocab%2Frelationship%2F%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0AWITH%20%3Curn%3Aspin%3Ananotation%3Ademo%3Aroyal%3Afamily%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fperson%20%3C%23hasUncle%3E%20as%20%3Frelation%20%3FhasUncle%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20a%20%3C%23RoyalPerson%3E%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%23hasUncle%3E%20%3FhasUncle%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000#hasUncle)
5. [Cousins](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=DEFINE%20input%3Amacro-lib%20%3Curn%3Aspin%3Ananotation%3Ademo%3Aroyal%3Afamily%3Alib%3E%20%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20rel%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fvocab%2Frelationship%2F%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0AWITH%20%3Curn%3Aspin%3Ananotation%3Ademo%3Aroyal%3Afamily%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fperson%20%3C%23hasCousin%3E%20as%20%3Frelation%20%3FhasCousin%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20a%20%3C%23RoyalPerson%3E%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%23hasCousin%3E%20%3FhasCousin%20%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000)

Here are links to posts about this functionality:

1. [Virtuoso 8.x Custom Inference Rules & Magic Predicates](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/magic-sets-and-custom-inference-rules-in-virtuoso-8-x-db783f8d98d2)
2. [How To Create Custom Inference Rules using Virtuoso 8.x](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/virtuoso-8-0-creating-a-custom-inference-rules-using-spin-vocabulary-d7a060f859ef)